# Get second point from point and direction in 3d space

Tags: javascript, math

I have a point:

```
x1 = 100;
z1 = 100;
y1 = 100;
```

And 2 directions:

```
xDir = Math.PI;
yDir = 0.11;
```

And a range:

```
range = 100;
```

How can I calculate the end point when constructing a ray from this information. I have tried the following:

```
x2 = x1 + (range * Math.cos(xDir))
z2 = z1 + (range * Math.sin(xDir))
y2 = y1 + (range * Math.cos(yDir))
```

But this doesn't work when the ray is pointing anywhere but at a perfect horizontal direction. Because I don't take yDir into account in the first 2 lines. How can I find the correct end point?

Comment: more like a math question instead of code problem.

Comment: The result's z coordinate shouldn't be affected, if the direction's z coordinate is 0

Comment: @GalAbra the xDirection affects the end points x and z coordinate. z Isnt 0

Comment: @SidneydeVries Aren't `xDir, yDir` the direction vector's coordinates?

Comment: @GalAbra those are the directions of the camera for the raycast. xDir is the left and right rotation. yDir is up and down

Comment: @SidneydeVries Then you're nor working with a regular vector system. I suggest you explain further your system of angles and directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to work with azimuth/inclination angles in [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (specific system - with OXZ equatorial plane).

In this case you need to account for Y when working with X/Z:

```
x2 = x1 + (range * Math.cos(xDir) * Math.sin(yDir))
z2 = z1 + (range * Math.sin(xDir) * Math.sin(yDir))
y2 = y1 + (range * Math.cos(yDir))
```